# How to change running port address for wmi exporter?

Tags: wmi

> For prometheus i am able to change the port address by giving this command **./prometheus --web.listen-address=localhost:5501**
>
> But in WMI exporter **--web.listen-address** command is not working. Kindly assist me on this

Comment: i found LISTEN_PORT is the flag need to use, but dont no how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .\wmi_exporter.exe --telemetry.addr=":9800"
>
> Run the above command to run the port at 9800 , user can change any port address